# Check if header is included using preprocessing directives?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to test whether a file has been included using preprocessing directives?

I wanted to achieve something like this:

```
#ifincluded assert.h
#error "Should not include assert.h"
#endif
```

At the moment, I solve this knowing that `assert.h` has defined `_ASSERT_H`. In this case, I can use `#ifdef _ASSERT_H`. The problem is that this is implementation specific.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: No there's no such (standardized and portable) way to check for already included header files.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What's the problem with including `assert.h` that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: If you need the header then include it. It doesn't matter if it has already been transitively included - header guards take care of that and it costs next to nothing. Include what you use where you use it - always.

Comment: <assert.h> is peculiar among the standard headers in that it is **designed** to be included multiple times, with different semantics (depending on whether `NDEBUG` is defined at the point of inclusion), in the same translation unit. That lets you turn asserts on or off for different regions of code. Is this question about **that header** or about "normal" headers, that can be included multiple times but always mean the same thing?

Comment: @melpomene The problem is that I have my custom assert function. I want calls to `assert` to call my own assertion function. However, if the developers keep including the header `<assert.h>` it will overwrite my definition of assertion. So, I want to raise a compilation error if any developer tries to include the header.

Comment: I think you will need to rely on the header guard being defined in `<assert.h>` (for C) or `<cassert>` (for C++), alas, which will be non-portable.  But you can detect it for your current platforms, a priori.  Assume those headers actually have header guards.

Comment: @rkioji Why is your custom function called `assert`? Why not choose a name that doesn't conflict with the standard library?

Comment: @melpomene My actual assert function is called `mylib_assert`. But my code database is large with existing calls to legacy `assert`. I want all calls to assert also call mylib_assert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply make use of the fact that `assert()` itself is a macro, so you could just do an

```
#ifdef assert
#error "Should not include assert.h"
#endif
```

This would, of course, also complain in case someone defines their own `assert` macro, which would, strictly speaking, be a legal thing to do [as long as they don't include any standard header](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#macro.names-1)…

At the end of the day, I would reconsider whatever it is exactly that you think you're trying to do here. If you're at a point where you have to make sure someone does not include a specific standard header, you're most likely on the wrong path and there's most likely a much better but completely different approach to be found if you just take a step back and rethink from the very beginning. So

> Is there a better way to achieve this?

Almost certainly. But it will not have anything to do with detecting and adjusting behavior depending on whether specific parts of the standard library have been included or not…

Comment: I still want to use my custom implementation of assert, so this does not work for me. I need a directive to test whether the <assert.h> header has been included and raise a compilation error.

Comment: @rkioji Why does this not work for you? You're concerned about conflicting definitions of `assert`, so `#ifdef assert` should be pretty much perfect.

Comment: I want the function assert to exist. I just do not want it to be the one from the header <assert.h>. Using `#ifdef assert` regardless of whether it is from my library or from the std libs.

Comment: @rkioji I don't understand the problem. In your library header, you do the `#ifdef` check first, then `#define assert mylib_assert`.

Comment: @melpomene It is already that way. But this will set the assert keyword to `whatever_you_want()` until the point where we include again the `<assert.h>`.

Comment: @rkioji Yes. How would checking for `#include` help with that? If someone includes your header first and `<assert.h>` afterwards, your hypothetical `#ifincluded` isn't a solution either.

Comment: @melpomene It will raise an error for the inclusion of the header `<assert.h>`. I just want to raise an error if somebody tries to include such header.

Comment: @rkioji How will it do that if `<assert.h>` hasn't been included yet?

Comment: @melpomene It will not cover all the situations. But eventually it will raise an error and we will know that we are not allowed to use such header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179678/discussion-between-melpomene-and-rkioji).